# How to position a button programmatically - UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to programmatically place a button at bottom right of my screen. Button should place at 25% of height and width of screen(on bottom right).How can I done it programmatically?

```
var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
ScreenHeight= (int)displayInformation.ScreenHeightInRawPixels;//1080
ScreenWidth= (int)displayInformation.ScreenWidthInRawPixels;//1920

  <Button x:Name="btnTest"   VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
```

Comment: you can use `testButton.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;`
           `testButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;`

Comment: 2 Questions: 
1.) Are you sure you want the screenheight and width? And not the size of your application?
2.) From where do you measure the distance? 25% space from the top/left corner of the button or from the bottom/right corner?

Comment: I want the size of application. How will it get?25% space from bottom/right corner

Comment: @nsds See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment, you want the distance from the bottom/right corner. You can achive that, by setting the margin of the button and setting the alignments.
To make the margin depending the application/page size you can use the following snippet:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.SizeChanged += MainPage_SizeChanged;
        }

        private void MainPage_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var height = this.ActualHeight;
            var width = this.ActualWidth;

            btnTest.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0.25 * width, 0.25 * height);
        }
    }
```

You can either set the alignment in the `MainPage_SizeChanged`:

```
btnTest.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
btnTest.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
```

Another option is to set the alignment in the xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```